# How to specify os platform in waf script?

Tags: waf

I'm new to waf build tool and I've googled for answers but very few unhelpful links.

Does anyone know?

As wscript is essentially a python script, I suppose I could use the `os` package?

Comment: You can use `import os` everywhere you could do it in any other python script. `wscript`s are (more or less) platform agnostic - depending on what code you put into it. I personally use `platform` and not `os` for that case. If I have things that behave different on Windows and Linux/Unix, I use something like that `if platform.system().lower().startswith('win'):
    a = 'x'
else:
    a = 'y'`. Does this answer your question? Then I will put a complete example as answer.

Comment: @user69453: I suggest you make your comment an answer. You could edit if the question changes.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the `os` module, instead use the `DEST_*` variables:

```py
ctx.load('compiler_c')
print (ctx.env.DEST_OS, ctx.env.DEST_CPU, ctx.env.DEST_BINFMT)
```

On my machine this would print `('linux', 'x86_64', 'elf')`. Then you can dispatch on that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `import` at every point where you could use it any other python script.

I prefer using `platform` for programming a function os-agnostic instead on evaluate some attributes of `os`.

Writing the [Build-related commands](https://waf.io/book/#_build_related_commands) example in the [waf book](https://waf.io/book/) os-agnostic, could look something like this:

```py
import platform

top = '.'
out = 'build_directory'

def configure(ctx):
    pass

def build(ctx):
    if platform.system().lower().startswith('win'):
        cp = 'copy'
    else:
        cp = 'cp'
    ctx(rule=cp+' ${SRC} ${TGT}', source='foo.txt', target='bar.txt')
```